# python unbound local error in for loop function

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, face-detection, haar-classifier

I try to make face detection and recognition using OpenCV that capture image/video from pc cam. But when I run it this error happen

```
$ python face_recog.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_recog.py", line 28, in <module>
    if face_extractor(frame) is not None:
  File "face_recog.py", line 19, in face_extractor
    return cropped_face | ''
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cropped_face' referenced before assignment
```

Here the full code for my app. Basically, it imports the library and reads haar cascade object lib in the XML file. and then use face_extractor function to read image/video from cam

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


face_path = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

def face_extractor(img):
    #img_umat = cv2.UMat(img)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face = face_path.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    
    if face in ():
        return None

        
    for(x, y, w, h) in face:
        cropped_face = img[y: y+h, x: x+w]
        
    return cropped_face 
        
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) #captureDevice = camera
count = 0

while True:
    
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    
    if face_extractor(frame) is not None:
        
        count = count + 1
        face = cv2.resize(face_extractor(frame), (200, 200))
        #face_umat = cv2.UMat(face)
        face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            
        output_path = "C:/Users/bryan/Desktop/test/Cascade/Output_img/user"+str(count)+".jpg"
        cv2.imwrite(output_path, face)
                
        cv2.putText(face, str(count), (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("face cropper", face)
            
    else:
        print("FACE NOT FOUND !")
        pass
        
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 13 or count == 100:
        break
        
capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("ALL SAMPLES COLLECTED !!")
```

Comment: `if face in ():` will always be False, AFAIK. Thus, if `face` is empty, then `cropped_face` is undefined. Try changing `if face in ():` to `if not face:`.

Comment: What is `type(face)`?

Comment: Try `if not face.length():` or something else that tests whether `face` is empty. It all depends on what `type(face)` is.

Comment: face value come from face_path.detectMultiScale

Answer (score 1):

`detectMultiScale` returns a list of tuples where each element in this list gives you the top left corner of where a face was detected as well as the width and height of the extent of the face.  This returns an empty list if you detect no faces, so `if face in ()` makes absolutely no sense.  What you are essentially doing is checking to see if `face` (which is a list) is contained inside an empty tuple which is always going to be `False` as there are no elements in this tuple.  Once that proceeds, you will potentially have an image with no faces, so the second `for` loop doesn't execute because `face` would be an empty list.  `cropped_face` is never assigned to anything and thus your error is produced.

As suggested by the comments, check to see if the list is empty by doing `if not face` instead.

Also supposing you have faces detected, the next `for` loop will only return the last face in the `face` list as the `cropped_face` variable keeps overwriting itself.  You may want to return a list of crops if you have more than one face detected instead:

```
def face_extractor(img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face = face_path.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    
    if not face:  # Change
        return None

    return [img[y:y+h, x:x+w] for (x, y, w, h) in face] # Change
```

## Minor Note

I would argue that you can get rid of the first `if` statement because if the `face` list is empty, the second `for` loop written above will also return an empty list.  Unless you are specifically ensuring that `None` is returned if there are no faces, you could really just do:

```
def face_extractor(img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face = face_path.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    
    return [img[y:y+h, x:x+w] for (x, y, w, h) in face] # Change
```

The empty list implicitly means no faces were detected which would be more uniform in terms of what is being returned - a list of faces which can be empty vs. a list of faces and `None` for the edge case if we detect no faces.

---

Judging from your use case, it appears that only one face is ever going to be detected at one time, so a cheap way to do this is to simply sample into the list and grab the first face.  This is not the way I would do this long-term, but to be compatible with the rest of your code let's do that.

```
def face_extractor(img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face = face_path.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    if not face:  # Change
        return None

    (x, y, w, h) = face[0]  # Change
    cropped_face = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    return cropped_face
```

I am maintaining that you return `None` if no faces can be found because now we're just returning a single crop instead of a list.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_recog.py", line 23, in <module>
    face = cv2.resize(face_extractor(frame), (200, 200))
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'


got this instead when resizing the frame

Comment: That's because you're doing `if face_extractor(frame) is not None:`.  If you are using the second version of the code, your function no longer returns `None`, so if you insist on doing it this way, you need to do `if face_extractor(frame)`.  However, you are calling this unnecessarily as you're doing it again in the `if` statement.  I would call it once, then reference the variable again inside the `if` statement.

Comment: I already use your second code. but if use if face_extractor(frame): it will be going to else statement which is face not found and got looping forever instead

Comment: the problem now when resizing the image. maybe if the return that your function does was different array form from before return. how to fix this?

Comment: The output is now a *list* of images.  Remember there's more than one face that can be detected.  However, we can modify the code so that if only one face is detected, we'll return just that face.  I'll change it for you.

Comment: should I do looping again to read, only every one element in the array?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  I've modified the code so that it returns one face.  If you want to use the version of the code that outputted a list, you will need to loop through every image in the list and write that to file.